# Using functions or methods in Java's String.replaceAll() regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to convert an RPN-equation into a string that matches tigcc rules. There numbers must have the number of chars in front of them and a tag for positive or negative. For "2" it would be "1 2 POSINT_TAG"

My complete input to rpn converter is based on regexes, so I wanted to use them again and have a `String.replaceAll()` function like:

```
string.replaceAll("(\d+)","$1".length+" $1 POSINT_TAG");
```

But there it just prints: "2 number INT_TAG". I found some classes like com.stevesoft.pat ([link](http://www.javaregex.com/)).

Is there another way implemented in normal Sun Java to use (custom) functions in replace rules of regexes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, at least not the same way you would do it in C# or Ruby.

The closest thing is to write a loop like this:

```
static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
String convert(String input) {
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String rep =
            String.format("%d %s POSINT_TAG",
                          matcher.group().length(),
                          matcher.group());
        matcher.appendReplacement(output, rep);
    }
    matcher.appendTail(output);
    return output.toString();
}
```

Comment: FYI, though StringBuilder is generally preferred, `appendReplacement()` and `appendTail()` do not accept it; you have to use StringBuffer instead.  (StringBuilder did not exist yet when the Matcher class was added, in JDK 1.4.)

Comment: +1 to the comment - I keep hoping they'll add an overloading of these methods that can take any `Appendable` but (as of the current Java 8 builds) there's still only the `StringBuffer` version.

Comment: You may be amused to know that [this answer is cited in the source code for the Stack Overflow mobile app for Android](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277077/254929).

Answer (score 3):

I have a idea about custom string replacement in Java. Not as easy as replacement function  in JavaScript but it just works fine. Here is the code:

```
    package org.eve.util;

    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class StringUtils{
        public static String replaceWithFn(CharSequence input,String regexp,Method fn,int group){
            Matcher m=Pattern.compile(regexp).matcher(input);
            StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
            try {
                Object obj=Modifier.toString(fn.getModifiers()).indexOf("static")>-1?
                        fn.getClass():fn.getDeclaringClass().newInstance();
                if(fn.getReturnType()!=String.class){
                    System.out.println("replacement function must return type \"String\".");
                }
                while(m.find()){
                    m.appendReplacement(sb, (String)fn.invoke(obj, m.group(group)));
                }
                m.appendTail(sb);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
```

`package org.eve.test;`

```
import org.eve.util.StringUtils;

public class ReplaceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            StringBuffer input=new StringBuffer("\\u039D\\u03B9\\u03BA\\u03CC\\u03BB\\u03B1\\u03BF\\u03C2 Nicholas \\u5C3C\\u53E4\\u62C9\\u65AF");
            System.out.println("input="+input);
            String result=StringUtils.replaceWithFn(
                input,
                "\\\\u([0-9a-zA-Z]{4})",
                ReplaceTest.class.getMethod("hex2char",String.class),
                1
            );
            System.out.println("output="+result);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String hex2char(String s){
        //TODO replaceholder
        return String.valueOf((char)Integer.parseInt(s,16));
    }
}
```

Just for fun.

Comment: This works perfectly! I used an interface instead of reflection:
https://github.com/redstone/LegacyFactions/blob/fcf1410e99cbe1e82fabcf84827b44e01af719a6/src/main/java/net/redstoneore/legacyfactions/util/StringUtils.java#L8

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately what you are attempting here isn't going to work. Java uses applicative order evaluation meaning that the arguments are evaluated before the function is ever called. In your case you are getting the length of the two-character string `"$1"`, not the number of digits that will be captured in group #1.

So when you use this line:

```
string.replaceAll("(\\d+)","$1".length+" $1 POSINT_TAG");
```

What the function sees is:

```
string.replaceAll("(\\d+)","2 $1 POSINT_TAG");
```

As for a solution to your problem, the answer posted by finnw will work.